# ASP.net core identity 2.0: proper way to use claims identity with db lookup?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, claims-based-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm new to the concept of claims-based identity so if the question is unclear, please let me know.

I've got a derived user collection, and it relates to an "organizations" collection. A user can be an admin in related organizations.

I'm trying to build the ability to have an [IsAdminForThisOrg] attribute which would apply for routes like:

```
.../api/Organizations/1/UpdateData
```

First, I'm thinking through "roles" vs "claims". It seems like roles would be a better fit if you were an admin, full stop (not considering the fact that in reality, your admin power only applies to a particular organization).

Then, reading more it seems like claims are a great fit for what I'm trying to accomplish. My thought is, on sign in, I'll look up all the orgs where a user is an admin, and then set a claim with a string.concat of those values. Then, I could build a policy around this claim.

### Question 1

Does my overall approach to this sound reasonable?

### Question 2

Is it correct that adding claims typically happens when the user signs in? Why is it that this official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims makes no mention of adding claims? How is this useful if you don't add claims?

### Question 3

What's the correct way to add claims when a user signs in? I did some digging and I'm overriding GenerateClaimsAsync in my own derived UserClaimsPrincipalFactory . It appears to be working. But the problem I'm hitting is:

```
protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
```

I'm getting passed in a user object, but I need to navigate to related data. The user has a collection navigation property to Organizations, but it's not populated yet because of the way EF loading works I believe. I don't know how to specify eager or explicit loading since I don't have a context and it appears this was already done for me. (I don't know what is passing me the user object into this method.0 Perhaps there's an entirely different way to populate claims which is preferable. There appears to be very little documentation on this method, so perhaps this is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already figured this out some way, but here's my thought however: you could take the dbcontext as a constructor parameter (dependency injection) for your own UserClaimsPrincipalFactory, and then query the needed organizations based on the user you get.